# How to convert 3D tensor to 2D tensor in pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am new to pytorch. I have 3D tensor (32,10,64) and I want a 2D tensor (32, 64).
I tried `view()` and used after passing to linear layer `squeeze()` which converted it to (32,10).

Comment: in what way does the output relate to the input int this case? you have x10 more inputs that outputs. Do you want to *sample* from the input? do you want to *combine* the inputs to form the output? you need to be more specific...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
t = torch.rand(32, 10, 64).permute(0, 2, 1)[:, :, -1]
```

or, as pointed out by [Shai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53474056/how-to-convert-3d-tensor-to-2d-tensor-in-pytorch/53475089?noredirect=1#comment93868946_53475089), you could also

```
t = torch.rand(32, 10, 64)[:, -1, :]


print(t.size()) # torch.Size([32, 64])
```

Comment: why `permute()`?? how is it different from simply `t[:, -1, :]`?

Comment: @Shai You can do that as well, its more straightforward :)